# Modifying the animation in FlexSlider

Tags: jquery, flexslider

Using FlexSlider for a client's site. They request that when one of "dots" at the bottom is clicked, it does not animate through all the images but only to the one that was selected.

I'm not sure what part of the code is controlling this and I have tried numerous hacks but without results!

Appreciate anyone's input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use **fade** effect instead of **slide** one?
In this can you can just add *animation* parameter in FlexSlider settings:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      // other settings
});
```

This way when you click on one "dot" it shows you only the related image.